# Adobe ActionScript and advanced graphics

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics

I am a beginner in Adobe ActionScript and I want to know if such a programming language has the ability to create the complexe graphics such as béziers, splines, gradient fills and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As3 supports gradient fills, but as far as curves go, currently there is support for [quadratic cuves](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#curveTo%28%29), although Flash Player 11 will support cubic curves by default in the drawing API.

Still, there are free libraries like [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) that are more feature rich ([beziers/splines](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#curveTo%28%29)/etc)

Comment: Does AS3 code replace completely the design part of Flash authoring tool?

Comment: I wouldn't say completely. The basic stuff is there, but not every single option from the drawing tools is avaialable in as3. For example: strokes - you've got thickness, colour, caps, joints etc. - but you don't have dashed/dotted/stylized lines in as3 by default, degrafa has support for dashed line and such decorations. with curves, as mentioned, in default as3 you've got quadratic, while the PenTool in authoring uses cubic curve (but again, Degrafa can draw cubic curves). There is support for primitive shapes (circle,rectangle,round rectangle even(but not documented), but not Star/Poly)...

Comment: ...there isn't a default 'Pencil' or 'Brush' tool for example, but you could implement one if needed. Regarding fills, AFAIK there are all supported.